# ASP.Net Core Serilog How to read from log file during runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, logging, serilog

I'm working on a ASP.NET Core 3.1 application. I want to log events to file and be able to read them during application runtime. To do that I'm trying to use [Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File) NuGet package and then specifying log file path as following:

**Startup.cs**

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ILoggerFactory logFactory)
 {
     logFactory.AddFile("Log");
 }
```

Any attempt to read or write to file like this way

```
string ReadLog(string logPath)
{
    return System.IO.File.ReadAllText(logPath);
}
```

ends in `System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file {log-path} because it is being used by another process.'` exception.

---

**EDIT**: I have installed [Serilog.AspNetCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.AspNetCore/3.2.0?_src=template) and made changes shown below while also removing logFactory from Configure function. **But exception continues to occur.**

**Program.cs**

```
public static int Main(string[] args)
{
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .MinimumLevel.Debug()
        .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Information)
        .Enrich.FromLogContext()
        .WriteTo.Console()
        .WriteTo.File(
            "Logs/log-.txt", 
            shared: true,
            flushToDiskInterval: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
            rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
        .CreateLogger();

    try
    {
        Log.Information("Starting web host");
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        return 0;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Fatal(ex, "Host terminated unexpectedly");
        return 1;
    }
    finally
    {
        Log.CloseAndFlush();
    }
}

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        }).UseSerilog();
```

**EDIT 2**:
As requested by **julealgon** I'm sharing my exact read logic. I'm trying to read using a controller, which I declared following way:

```
[Controller]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class LogController : Controller
{
    [Route("Read")]
    public IActionResult ReadLog(string logPath)
    {
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(logPath))
        {
            string logContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(logPath);//exception appears here.
            return Content(logContent);
        }
        else return NotFound();
    }
}
```

Then using example query below to read log recorded by Friday, March 13, 2020.

```
https://localhost:44323/Log/Read?logPath=Logs\log-20200313.txt
```

Comment: You might want to review how you are configuring the logger. The recommended approach is to configure it on `Program.cs` using `AddSerilog` extension from [here](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore/blob/dev/src/Serilog.AspNetCore/SerilogWebHostBuilderExtensions.cs).

Comment: From [documentation](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-logging-file#additional-configuration), AddFile() method seems not accept `shared` parameter.

Comment: Can you share your exact reading logic? Is this really your file path `"Logs/log-.txt"`?

Comment: @julealgon Sure. Check out my updated question please.

Answer (score 9):

When configuring the `File` sink, there is an overload that provides a `shared` Boolean argument. If you set that to `true` (it's `false` by default) you should then be able to read the contents of the file somewhere else in your application.

Comment: Yep! https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file - To enable multi-process shared log files, set shared to true: `.WriteTo.File("log.txt", shared: true)`

Comment: does not seem to be working for me.  using StreamReader elsewhere in .Net 6 application still gives "it is being used by another process"

Comment: @PBMe_HikeIt can you post how you are creating the `StreamReader` instance? Are you explicitly passing the share option on the constructor? If not, can you give that a try?

Comment: @julealgon, I was not passing that and doing that fixed the problem. thanks!

Answer (score 8):

When reading the file, I think use something like this will work:

```cs
using (var stream = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    return reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

The trick appears to be the specification of `FileShare.ReadWrite` as this is the policy used to write to when the sink opens the log file to write to. There's a [similar bug reported](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file/issues/109) over in the `serilog-sinks-file` repo.

Comment: c# 6 does not have 'ReadAllBytes'

Comment: @OverMars - yes, you're right, that was my bad when I wrote the answer, ReadAllBytes is an extension method I have in a common library. I've updated the answer with something that should be logically equivalent.